# Image not showing in Flutter Splash Screen page

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My Image.asset file doesn't display my image but other widgets display text, card, etc

assets:
  - images/internet_image.jpg

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => 
_SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Image.asset(
                'images/internet_image.jpg',
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1/4,
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Two possibilities spring to mind:
1. asset case sensitive spelling error.
2. Scaffold doesn't return a context for the Navigator so maybe it not returning a context here.  So maybe we need an extra layer of widgets.

Comment: do you have an error? Did you add the asset to your pubspec.yaml ?

Answer (score 4):

assets: - images/downloaded_image.jpg

and the referenced asset should be the same:

```
Image.asset('images/downloaded_image.jpg'),
```

In your code you refer to an asset named *images/internet_image.jpg*

Comment: Sorry, that's not the issue. That mistake was made on stackoverflow because I was testing with two images so I mixed things up

Comment: @Chike is the images folder in the root project folder? If not change the path acordingly in pubspec.yaml and in the code. Also if you get an error please include it in your question too.

Answer (score 0):

An extra layer of widget might look like the code below so that the Scaffold doesn't have to field the context call.

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() =>
      _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SplashScreenStack(),
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreenStack extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.asset(
              'images/internet_image.jpg',
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1/4,
              fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot every one for answering. All solutions provided would definitely fix the issue, I decided to upload my splash screen the normal way via pubspec.yaml rather than trying to create a splash screen page.